# convert string calculation to value of calculation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"(12.0+10)*31"
```

I need to be able to convert that to the value:

```
(12.0+10)*31 = 682
```

I have tried some obvious ones like .to_f but that didn't work

I only care about the value (682), I don't really need to see the calculation.

I am sure there is some easy rails thing that does this that I can't find.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eval for this, i.e. in IRB:

```
>> eval "(12.0+10)*31"
=> 682.0
```

Then if it needs to be an integer you just call to_i on the result.

ian.

Comment: Accept my answer, perhaps? :)

Comment: had to wait for a timer for some reason.